# Configuring setup.py for PyPi package

Tags: python, pypi

```py
from distutils.core import setup


setup(
    name="example",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Author",
    author_email="reandom_emal@email.com",
    packages=["example", "example.test"],
    url="http://pypi.python.org/pypi/example/",
    license="LICENSE.txt",
    include_package_data=True,
    description="long description",
    long_description=open("README.txt").read(),
    install_requires=[
        "appnope",
        "backcall",
        "blis",
        "beautifulsoup4",
        "bs4",
        "catalogue",
        "certifi",
        "chardet",
        "click",
        "cloudpickle",
        "colorama",
        "configparser",
        "crayons",
        "cssselect",
        "cycler",
        "cymem",
        "cytoolz",
        "DateTime",
        "decorator",
        "deprecation",
        "dill",
        "feedfinder2",
        "feedparser",
        "filelock",
        "frozendict",
        "fsspec",
        "HeapDict",
        "idna",
        "ipython",
        "ipython-genutils",
        "jedi",
        "jieba3k",
        "Jinja2",
        "joblib",
        "kiwisolver",
        "locket",
        "lxml",
        "matplotlib",
        "murmurhash",
        "newspaper3k",
        "nltk",
        "numpy",
        "olefile",
        "pandas",
        "parso",
        "partd",
        "pathy",
        "pexpect",
        "pickleshare",
        "preshed",
        "prompt-toolkit",
        "psutil",
        "ptyprocess",
        "pydantic",
        "Pygments",
        "pyparsing",
        "python-dateutil",
        "pytz",
        "PyYAML",
        "regex",
        "requests",
        "requests-file",
        "selenium",
        "sgmllib3k",
        "smart-open",
        "socketIO-client-nexus",
        "soupsieve",
        "spacy",
        "spacy-legacy",
        "six",
        "srsly",
        "sseclient",
        "temporal-cache",
        "thinc",
        "tinysegmenter",
        "tldextract",
        "tqdm0",
        "traitlets",
        "typer",
        "tzlocal",
        "urllib3",
        "wasabi",
        "wcwidth",
        "webdriver-manager",
        "websocket-client",
        "websockets",
        "zict",
        "zope.interface",
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        " https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl"
    ],
)
```

I am trying to publish my python project to PyPi as a package following [this](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) tutorial. It publishes fine to test PyPI, but when I try to download it from test PyPI I get an error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bs4 (from example==0.0.1) (from versions: none)
```

I tried and reuploaded the same file (as a different package) but with a valid version number, but now I got another error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement appnope==0.1.2 (from example==0.0.1) (from versions: none)
```

I don't really understand where this error is coming from and how to make my package installable from PyPi?

Comment: From the error, it shows a problem with appnope package,  to find problem root, try to install it separately and see if it get installed without errors or not, pip install appnope

Comment: This is not a problem with an individual package, when I tried to remove appnope from the installation list I got the same error for other packages like blist, bs4, and other packages. I think there is some problem with the way I specify dependencies in the setup.py configuration(because I can install each package individually perfectly fine with pip)